# Dartpad make request with basic auth

Tags: dart, http-headers, basic-authentication, dartpad

How to make a `basic auth request` against [httpbin.org/basic-auth](https://httpbin.org/#/Auth/get_basic_auth__user___passwd_) using

- `http.get()` works
- `http.Request()` fails

with dartpad. This is [my dartpad-demo-code](https://dartpad.dev/?id=4a68e553746602d851ab3da6aeafc3dd)

#### What is working

Using `get()` finally works

```dart
import 'dart:convert' as convert;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main(List<String> arguments) async {

  final url_httpbin = Uri.https('httpbin.org', '/basic-auth/myuser/mypasswd');  
  
  var base64Encoder = convert.Base64Encoder(); 
  var creds64 = base64Encoder.convert('myuser:mypasswd'.codeUnits);
  Map<String, String> authHeader = {'Authorization':'Basic $creds64'};  
    
  final response = await http.get(url_httpbin, 
       headers: authHeader); // sending headers with basic auth

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
    print('Repsonse $jsonResponse');
  } else {
    print('Request failed with status: ${response.statusCode}.');
  }
}
```

#### Question How can `Request` be used

My attempt to use the `Request()` class fails

```dart
var request = http.Request('GET', url_httpbin);
request.headers(authHeader); // <-- error
```

The last line returns

> Error compiling to JavaScript: lib/main.dart:23:18: Error: 'headers'
> isn't a function or method and can't be invoked.
> request.headers(authHeader);
> ^^^^^^^ Error: Compilation failed.

Or this

```dart
 request.headers = authHeader; // error
```

Results in

> Error compiling to JavaScript: lib/main.dart:23:11: Error: The setter
> 'headers' isn't defined for the class 'Request'.
>
> - 'Request' is from 'package:http/src/request.dart' ('/app/local_pub_cache/hosted/pub.dev/http-1.1.0/lib/src/request.dart').
>   request.headers = authHeader;
>   ^^^^^^^ Error: Compilation failed.

From the [Request class documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/Request-class.html) it is unclear to me how i can use the class to make an http request.

Comment: Vote for [add example to docs](https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/1021)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the headers using `Request` you need to fill the map returned by `Request.headers`, for example:

```
request.headers['HeaderName'] = 'Value';
```

then to send it you need to call `Client.send` on an instance of `Client` to send the request, which will returned a `StreamedResponse` (meaning that the body is not known in advance); you can then get a `Response` using `Response.fromStream`.

Here is a full example:

```
  final client = Client();
  final request = Request('GET', url_httpbin);

  request.headers['HeaderName'] = 'Value';

  final streamedResponse = await client.send(request);
  final response = await Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);

  // Do your stuff ...
  
  client.close();
```

Comment: Thanks this looks good - see [dartpad code](https://dartpad.dev/?id=3d7c6619214dfe2a681648e9dd739be0)

Comment: Vote for [add example to docs](https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/1021)